# How can I find special markers like "{{e3}}" in text and replace them with matching data from a list?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list called `effectBurn`:

```
[
    "",
    "60/80/100/120/140",
    "2.5",
    "30",
    "",
    "20/40/60/80/100",
    "0.08",
    "0.15"
],
```

And I have a string that contains "{{ e1 }}" . How can I convert {{ e1 }} to `effectBurn[1]`, "{{ e2 }}" to `effectBurn[2]`, and e3, e4, ..?

For example:

```
"Spell effects: {{ e1 }}"
```

into

```
"Spell effects: 60/80/100/120/140"
```

Comment: It's entirely unclear to me what you mean by "and `e1` equals to `list[1]`". Basically, your question is unclear. Can you provide a [mcve]? (And what's this got to do with {{e3}} as per you subject?)

Comment: You can't.  In c# all inputs types must be known.  It looks like your input are following : empty string, forward slash separated integers, double, integer (or float).  Then the pattern repeats.

Comment: I didn't get what you are asking either

Comment: @JonSkeet  {{ e3 }} should be effectBurn[3] {{ e1 }} should be effectBurn[1]

Comment: It's still entirely unclear to me what you're asking.

Comment: I have a list called effectBurn. And i have a string that contains "{{ e1 }}" . How can i convert {{ e1 }} to effectBurn[1]

Comment: @AshkanSirous I have a list called effectBurn. And i have a string that contains "{{ e1 }}" . How can i convert {{ e1 }} to effectBurn[1]

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz what do you mean by converting  {{ e1 }} to effectBurn[1]? You make no sense :|

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz do you want to put "{{ e1 }}" in effectBurn[1]? or what/? you just make no sense

Comment: @AshkanSirous I want to replace "{{ e1 }}" with effectBurn[1] and "{{ e2 }}" with effectBurn[2] (Sorry bad english)

Comment: Basing on the solution you found and added here as answer, I tried to make the title and question less unclear. The problem was that the "{{e3}}" looks like a formatstring for .ToString method or many other things, whereas it was simply a part of the text you wanted to find. Also, the word "convert" was misleading - it usually means casting data to different type, or translating to another format, and you simply wanted to "replace" part of the string. That made the short question very hard to guess. Also,it would really help if you'd say that you want to change text `Foo: {{e3}}` to `Foo: 30`!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I do not write these data on my own, I get these from a json file. But thanks for explaining my mistakes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions.

```
int index = 0;
string pattern = @"{{\s*e\d+\s*}}";
string result = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, m => effectBurn[++index]);
```

Where `text` is your source string.

Answer (score 1):

That's the solution I Found Out:

```
string Replace(string s,List<string> list,List<Models.SpellVarsDto> vars) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            string s1 = "{{ e" + i.ToString() + " }}";
            if (s.Contains(s1))
            {
                string s2 = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(s1), s1.Length);
                s = s.Replace(s1, list[i]);

                spellDesc.Text = s;
                //MessageBox.Show(s + " " + s1 + " " + list[i]);
            }
            string s3 = "{{ a" + i.ToString() + " }}";
            if (s.Contains(s3))
            {
                foreach (Models.SpellVarsDto item in vars)
                {
                    if (item.key == "a" + i.ToString())
                    {
                        string s4 = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(s3), s3.Length);
                        s = s.Replace(s3, item.coeff[0].ToString());

                        spellDesc.Text = s;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks to this code I understood what you meant in question. It's good you added it here! It certainly works fine. However, if the list `vars` is long, it will work really slow. You may speed it up significantly by changing the `vars` from a List to a `Dictionary<string, SpellVarsDto>` indexed by `key` like `a2` a5` etc. You can build a dictionary easily with linq: `var myDictionary = vars.ToDictionary(item => item.key);`. Also, if `list` or `s` are long, it will be faster to use Regex to look for `{{ [ae]\d+ }}` pattern instead of building strings and searching via Contains.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Thanks for tips! But i get these lists from Json & the type should be list, is there any way to convert List to Dictionary?

Comment: Yes, I just wrote it in the comment. If you have a list called `vars` like in the function you pasted as answer, `List<Models.SpellVarsDto> vars`, you can turn it into a dictionary like that: `var myDictionary = vars.ToDictionary(item => item.key);`. Put that at the start of your function. Be sure to add `using System.Linq;`. Then you can get the values by simply `myDictionary["a3"]` instead of the whole foreach-spellvars loop.

Comment: Oh, and the Dictionary will throw if you try to get a "a3" and the dictionary doesn't contain it. You may need to check with `dict.ContainsKey("a3")` first. Of course you can use a variable instead of "a3", I just used a3 as an example.

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous. I will try to explain the simplest C# code maybe to help you. But really I don't have a clue about what exactly are you asking

If you have a variable and you want to put effectBurn[1]- ("60/80/100/120/140")- inside that, it is simple and there is no need to know what is inside that variable:

```
string myVariable= "{{ e1 }}"; 
myVariable = effectBurn[1];
```

if you want to put effectBurn[1] in {{}} chars, you can do it this way

```
myVariable ="{{"+ effectBurn[1]+"}}";
```

your question is not clear at all

Comment: Sorry for bad English :P                                                                                     That's the solution I found out: http://pasted.co/bc0633ae